# Xstate Getting warning: No implementation found for action type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xstate

I have similar actions `ADD_THOUGHT_TIME_STAMP` in two different states, so I tried moving that action to the `actions` of xStat, by fallowing the [official documentation](https://xstate.js.org/docs/guides/actions.html#declarative-actions).

But I keep getting an error: "No implementation found for action type addThoughtTimStamp"

Here is the code that **works**:

```
import { Machine, assign } from "xstate";
import {
  ADD_PRIMING_STAGE_ACTION,
  ADD_WORK_STAGE_ACTION,
  ADD_THOUGHT_TIME_STAMP,
  CREATE,
  GO_TO_RESULTS_ACTION,
  PRIMING,
  WORK,
  RESULTS,
  CREATE_NEW_TASK_ACTION,
} from "../types";

export const taskMachine = Machine({
  id: "taskMachineID",
  initial: CREATE,
  context: {
    taskName: "",
    taskStages: [],
  },
  states: {
    CREATE: {
      on: {
        [CREATE_NEW_TASK_ACTION]: {
          // CREATE_NEW TASK is an action.
          target: PRIMING,
          actions: assign((context, data) => {
            console.log("testing action works");
            return {
              ...context,
              taskName: data.taskName,
              taskStages: [{ stageName: "priming", timeOfThoughts: [] }],
            };
          }),
        },
      },
    },
    [PRIMING]: {
      on: {
        [ADD_WORK_STAGE_ACTION]: {
          target: WORK,
          actions: assign((context) => {
            return {
              ...context,
              taskStages: [
                ...context.taskStages,
                { stageName: "work", timeOfThoughts: [] },
              ],
            };
          }),
        },
        [ADD_THOUGHT_TIME_STAMP]: {
          actions: assign((context, { thoughtTime }) => {
            const lastStage =
              context.taskStages[context.taskStages.length - 1].timeOfThoughts;
            console.log(lastStage);
            lastStage.push(thoughtTime);
            return {
              ...context,
            };
          }),
        },
      },
    },
    [WORK]: {
      on: {
        [ADD_PRIMING_STAGE_ACTION]: {
          target: PRIMING,
          actions: assign((context) => {
            console.log("going to piming stage");
            return {
              ...context,
              taskStages: [
                ...context.taskStages,
                { stageName: "priming", timeOfThoughts: [] },
              ],
            };
          }),
        },
        [GO_TO_RESULTS_ACTION]: {
          target: RESULTS,
          actions: assign((context, data) => {
            console.log("task status: ", data);
          }),
        },
        [ADD_THOUGHT_TIME_STAMP]: {
          actions: assign((context, { thoughtTime }) => {
            const lastStage =
              context.taskStages[context.taskStages.length - 1].timeOfThoughts;
            console.log(lastStage);
            lastStage.push(thoughtTime);
            return {
              ...context,
            };
          }),
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Here is the code that **doesn't work**:

```
export const taskMachine = Machine({
  id: "taskMachineID",
  initial: CREATE,
  context: {
    taskName: "",
    taskStages: [],
  },
  states: {
    CREATE: {
      on: {
        [CREATE_NEW_TASK_ACTION]: {
          // CREATE_NEW TASK is an action.
          target: PRIMING,
          actions: assign((context, data) => {
            console.log("testing action works");
            return {
              ...context,
              taskName: data.taskName,
              taskStages: [{ stageName: "priming", timeOfThoughts: [] }],
            };
          }),
        },
      },
    },
    [PRIMING]: {
      on: {
        [ADD_WORK_STAGE_ACTION]: {
          target: WORK,
          actions: assign((context) => {
            return {
              ...context,
              taskStages: [
                ...context.taskStages,
                { stageName: "work", timeOfThoughts: [] },
              ],
            };
          }),
        },
        [ADD_THOUGHT_TIME_STAMP]: {
          actions: ["addThoughtTimStamp"],
        },
      },
    },
    [WORK]: {
      on: {
        [ADD_PRIMING_STAGE_ACTION]: {
          target: PRIMING,
          actions: assign((context) => {
            console.log("going to piming stage");
            return {
              ...context,
              taskStages: [
                ...context.taskStages,
                { stageName: "priming", timeOfThoughts: [] },
              ],
            };
          }),
        },
        [GO_TO_RESULTS_ACTION]: {
          target: RESULTS,
          actions: assign((context, data) => {
            console.log("task status: ", data);
          }),
        },
        [ADD_THOUGHT_TIME_STAMP]: {
          actions: ["addThoughtTimStamp"],
        },
      },
    },
    [RESULTS]: {},
  },
  actions: {
    addThoughtTimStamp: assign((context, { thoughtTime }) => {
      const lastStage =
        context.taskStages[context.taskStages.length - 1].timeOfThoughts;
      console.log(lastStage);
      lastStage.push(thoughtTime);
      return {
        ...context,
      };
    }),
  },
});
```

What am I missing?

P.S if you see other problems in my code feel free to comment, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Machine` constructor you have pass two arguments: config of your statechart and options for it, containing implementation of guards, actions, services and so on. In your "not working" example implementation goes into config, but should be inside options:

```js
let config = {
  id: "taskMachineID",
  initial: CREATE,
  context: {
    taskName: "",
    taskStages: [],
  },
  states: {
    CREATE: {
      on: {
        [CREATE_NEW_TASK_ACTION]: {
          // CREATE_NEW TASK is an action.
          target: PRIMING,
          actions: assign((context, data) => {
            console.log("testing action works");
            return {
              ...context,
              taskName: data.taskName,
              taskStages: [{ stageName: "priming", timeOfThoughts: [] }],
            };
          }),
        },
      },
    },
    [PRIMING]: {
      on: {
        [ADD_WORK_STAGE_ACTION]: {
          target: WORK,
          actions: assign((context) => {
            return {
              ...context,
              taskStages: [
                ...context.taskStages,
                { stageName: "work", timeOfThoughts: [] },
              ],
            };
          }),
        },
        [ADD_THOUGHT_TIME_STAMP]: {
          actions: ["addThoughtTimStamp"],
        },
      },
    },
    [WORK]: {
      on: {
        [ADD_PRIMING_STAGE_ACTION]: {
          target: PRIMING,
          actions: assign((context) => {
            console.log("going to piming stage");
            return {
              ...context,
              taskStages: [
                ...context.taskStages,
                { stageName: "priming", timeOfThoughts: [] },
              ],
            };
          }),
        },
        [GO_TO_RESULTS_ACTION]: {
          target: RESULTS,
          actions: assign((context, data) => {
            console.log("task status: ", data);
          }),
        },
        [ADD_THOUGHT_TIME_STAMP]: {
          actions: ["addThoughtTimStamp"],
        },
      },
    },
    [RESULTS]: {},
  },
};

let options = {
  actions: {
    addThoughtTimStamp: assign((context, { thoughtTime }) => {
      const lastStage =
        context.taskStages[context.taskStages.length - 1].timeOfThoughts;
      console.log(lastStage);
      lastStage.push(thoughtTime);
      return {
        ...context,
      };
    }),
  },
};

Machine(config, options);
```

Here is fixed example: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-johnson-d5cj2?file=/src/index.js